# Parse this custom data format for data type with nested list

Tags: rust, nom

I have this format, the result should be of Item data type,

**test 1:** `"<A \"Test\">"`

**test 2:** `r#"<A "Test">"#`

**Result:** `Item { item_type: TEXT, ascii_data: Some("Test") }`

**test 3:** `<A>`

**Result:** `Item { item_type: TEXT, ascii_data: None }`

For test 1 and test 2, following code parse, but for type 3, it is failing,

It also contains nested types.

```
<L 
    <A "Test1">
    <L
        <A>
        <A "Test2">
    >
    <A "Test3">
>
```

**Result:**

```
Item { 
    item_type: LIST,
    sub_items: [
        Item {
            item_type: ASCII,
            ascii_data: "Test1",
        },
        Item {
            item_type: LIST,
            sub_items: [
                Item {
                    item_type: ASCII,
                    ascii_data: None,
                    }
                Item {
                    item_type: ASCII,
                    ascii_data: "Test2",
                    }
                ], 
        },
        Item {
            item_type: ASCII,
            ascii_data: "Test3",
        },
    ],
}
```

##### Rust [Playgroud link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=11f11eb1189784af753d102c07c732bb)

```
use nom::{
    branch::alt,
    bytes::complete::{tag, take_until},
    character::complete::multispace0,
    combinator::map,
    IResult,
};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
enum ItemType {
    LIST,
    TEXT,
    NONE,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Item {
    item_type: ItemType,
    sub_items: Option<Vec<Item>>,
    ascii_data: Option<String>,
}

impl Default for Item {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Item {
            item_type: ItemType::NONE,
            sub_items: None,
            ascii_data: None,
        }
    }
}

// Parse string data, it may empty then return none,
fn parse_ascii_data(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, String> {
    let (input, _) = tag("\"")(input)?;
    let (input, ascii_data) = take_until("\"")(input)?;
    let (input, _) = tag("\"")(input)?;

    Ok((input, ascii_data.to_string()))
}

// Parse <A> or <A "string">, if no string then return empty string then return none
fn parse_ascii_item(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Item> {
    let (input, _) = tag("<A")(input)?;
    let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;
    let (input, ascii_data) = alt((parse_ascii_data, map(tag("\"\""), |_| "".to_string())))(input)?;
    let (input, _) = tag(">")(input)?;

    Ok((
        input,
        Item {
            item_type: ItemType::TEXT,
            ascii_data: Some(ascii_data),
            ..Default::default()
        },
    ))
}

// Parse <L> or <L <A "string">>, if no string then return empty string then return none
fn parse_list_item(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Item> {
    let (input, _) = tag("<L")(input)?;
    let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;
    let (input, sub_items) = alt((parse_ascii_item, map(tag("<>"), |_| Item::default())))(input)?;
    let (input, _) = tag(">")(input)?;

    Ok((
        input,
        Item {
            item_type: ItemType::LIST,
            sub_items: Some(vec![sub_items]),
            ..Default::default()
        },
    ))
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_ascii_item() {
        let input = "<A \"Test\">";

        let expected_item = Item {
            item_type: ItemType::TEXT,
            ascii_data: Some("Test".to_string()),
            ..Default::default()
        };

        assert_eq!(parse_ascii_item(input), Ok(("", expected_item)));

        let input = r#"<A "Test">"#;

        let expected_item = Item {
            item_type: ItemType::TEXT,
            ascii_data: Some("Test".to_string()),
            ..Default::default()
        };

        assert_eq!(parse_ascii_item(input), Ok(("", expected_item)));

        assert_eq!(
            parse_ascii_item("<A>"),
            Ok((
                "",
                Item {
                    item_type: ItemType::TEXT,
                    ascii_data: None,
                    ..Default::default()
                }
            ))
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_list_item() {
        let input = "<L <A \"Test\">>";

        let expected_item = Item {
            item_type: ItemType::LIST,
            sub_items: Some(vec![Item {
                item_type: ItemType::TEXT,
                ascii_data: Some("Test".to_string()),
                ..Default::default()
            }]),
            ..Default::default()
        };

        assert_eq!(parse_list_item(input), Ok(("", expected_item)));

        assert_eq!(
            parse_list_item("<L>"),
            Ok((
                "",
                Item {
                    item_type: ItemType::LIST,
                    sub_items: Some(vec![Item::default()]),
                    ..Default::default()
                }
            ))
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_nested_list_item() {
        let input = "<L \n    <A \"Test1\">\n    <L\n        <A \"Test2\">\n    >\n>";

        let expected_item = Item {
            item_type: ItemType::LIST,
            sub_items: Some(vec![Item {
                item_type: ItemType::TEXT,
                ascii_data: Some("Test".to_string()),
                ..Default::default()
            }]),
            ..Default::default()
        };

        assert_eq!(parse_list_item(input), Ok(("", expected_item)));

        assert_eq!(
            parse_list_item("<L>"),
            Ok((
                "",
                Item {
                    item_type: ItemType::LIST,
                    sub_items: Some(vec![Item::default()]),
                    ..Default::default()
                }
            ))
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `parse_ascii_item()` you don't want to use [`alt()`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/branch/fn.alt.html) you want to use [`opt()`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/combinator/fn.opt.html). While in `parse_list_item()` you actually do want do use [`alt()`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/branch/fn.alt.html).

The difference is that [`alt()`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/branch/fn.alt.html) executes the parsers one-by-one until one succeeds (if any). While in `parse_ascii_item()` you want to accept [`opt`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/combinator/fn.opt.html)ional `ascii_data`.

The fixed `parse_ascii_item()` looks like this:

```rust
fn parse_ascii_item(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Item> {
    let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;
    let (input, _) = tag("<A")(input)?;
    let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;
    let (input, ascii_data) = opt(parse_ascii_data)(input)?;
    let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;
    let (input, _) = tag(">")(input)?;

    Ok((
        input,
        Item {
            item_type: ItemType::TEXT,
            ascii_data,
            ..Default::default()
        },
    ))
}
```

Now in `parse_list_item()` we do actually want to use [`alt()`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/branch/fn.alt.html), since we want to accept either `parse_ascii_item()` or `parse_list_item()`. Additionally, since we want to accept zero-to-many of them, we also need to wrap it in [`many0()`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/multi/fn.many0.html).

The fixed `parse_list_item()` looks like this:

```rust
fn parse_list_item(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Item> {
    let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;
    let (input, _) = tag("<L")(input)?;
    let (input, mut sub_items) = many0(|input| {
        let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;
        alt((parse_ascii_item, parse_list_item))(input)
    })(input)?;
    let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;
    let (input, _) = tag(">")(input)?;

    if sub_items.is_empty() {
        sub_items.push(Item::default());
    }

    Ok((
        input,
        Item {
            item_type: ItemType::LIST,
            sub_items: Some(sub_items),
            ..Default::default()
        },
    ))
}
```

---

Additionally, your `test_parse_nested_list_item()` is wrong. At least your `input` doesn't reasonably match the `expected_item`. So I assume `expected_item` actually needs to look like this:

```rust
let expected_item = Item {
    item_type: ItemType::LIST,
    sub_items: Some(vec![
        Item {
            item_type: ItemType::TEXT,
            ascii_data: Some("Test1".to_string()),
            ..Default::default()
        },
        Item {
            item_type: ItemType::LIST,
            sub_items: Some(vec![Item {
                item_type: ItemType::TEXT,
                ascii_data: Some("Test2".to_string()),
                ..Default::default()
            }]),
            ..Default::default()
        },
    ]),
    ..Default::default()
};
```

---

Here's a complete example on [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=894b74c2c1ab2b5c13119ffa8ad80393).

---

As an aside, in the future remember to sprinkle [`multispace0()`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/character/complete/fn.multispace0.html) around, since you allow for optional whitespace in various places:

```rust
let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;
```

Another aside Rust's string literally allow for newlines. Additionally, instead of escaping `\"` you can also use [raw string literals](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#raw-string-literals):

```rust
// Before
let input = "<L \n    <A \"Test1\">\n    <L\n        <A \"Test2\">\n    >\n>";

// After:
let input = r#"
    <L
        <A "Test1">
        <L
            <A "Test2">
        >
    >"#;
```

Comment: One question, what modifications need to be made to if <A "test" // this is test
\n>
where // is showing comment?

Comment: @i_am_learning Check out the [nom recipes](https://github.com/rust-bakery/nom/blob/main/doc/nom_recipes.md#-ceol-style-comments) it has a line comment example

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but how can I parse the length, I am trying but getting error, `<L [1]\n <A "test">\n>`, the length is in bracket

Comment: I got it working, never mind,
    let (input, _) = multispace0(input)?;
    let (input, _) = opt(tag("["))(input)?;
    let (input, count) = opt(digit1)(input)?;
    let (input, _) = opt(tag("]"))(input)?;

Comment: Please create a new question instead for future issues :) Anyways, your problem is likely that you're separating them into multiple `opt`. Essentially what you have there would allow `<L 123 ...>` or `<L ] ...>`, which is likely causing issues. Instead wrap everything in `opt`, like this `let (input, count) = opt(tuple((tag("["), digit1, tag("]"))))(input)?;` Note that `count` is `Option<(&str, &str, &str)>`. You can also replace `digit1` with `map_res(digit1, |s| usize::from_str_radix(s, 10))` to parse the number immediately